# Puppeteer in-browser time acceleration

Tags: node.js, time, puppeteer

Is there some option, the opposite to `slowMo`, that accelerates in-browser time? What I want, is to play all the page scripts/intervals/animations as quick as it possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that this is achievable. You can slow down actions in the browser, as you pointed out by using the `slowMo` setting, but otherwise the browser acts just like it would if a user was interacting with it - that's kind of the point really :-)

The suggestions I can make to you are based on things I've tried and implemented from my own experiences with UI automation. Hopefully something in here can help you.

**What I want, is to play all the page scripts/intervals/animations as quick as it possible.**

As I've said already, I don't believe you will be able to do anything other than wait for the page the load normally as if a user was logging in to and / or interacting with your application. However you do have a very powerful option which can take some of the pain away from waiting for your page to load all of the time.

For example, you can use `jest-puppeteer`:
https://github.com/smooth-code/jest-puppeteer/tree/master/packages/jest-puppeteer

What `jest-puppeteer` allows you to do is structure your test suite(s) in a behaviour driven testing format using `describe` and `it` statements to define your suite and test scripts respectively. By using this method, you can specify a `before` method to be executed before all test scripts in the suite are executed - so in here you could, say, log into your application and have it wait for everything to load once and once only. All test scripts will then be executed sequentially on the page that is displayed in the remote browser without having to reload the browser and start all over again from scratch between tests.

This can significantly reduce the pain of having to wait for page loads every single time you want to run a test.

The idea is that you can bunch relevant tests scripts together in each suite - ie. in the first suite, load the login page once and then execute all login based test scripts before tearing down. In the next suite, load the home page once and then execute all home page based test scripts before tearing down. You get the idea.

This is the best recommendation I can personally give you. Hopefully it helps!